# Python __new__ metaclass behavior with inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, metaprogramming

I have two questions regarding the behavior of running the below code. Why is `__new__` even being called without instantiating an object? I thought `__new__` controlled the creation of a new *instance*. Next, why does `delattr` raise an **AttributeError** when `hasattr` returns **True** for *size*?

```
class ShapeBase(type):

  def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
    rv = super(ShapeBase, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
    parents = [base for base in bases if isinstance(base, ShapeBase)]

    # don't do anything unless this is a subclass of Shape
    if not parents:
      return rv

    print hasattr(rv, 'altitude') # prints True
    print rv.altitude             # prints 7
    del rv.altitude               # deletes altitude from rv

    print hasattr(rv, 'size')     # prints True
    print rv.size                 # prints 5
    delattr(rv, 'size')           # raises AttributeError                    

    return rv

class Shape(object):
  __metaclass__ = ShapeBase
  size = 5

class Triangle(Shape):
  altitude = 7
```

Comment: Your comment "don't do anything unless this is a subclass of Shape" is misleading, because what you're _doing_, is you're checking wheter it _inherits_ a class with `ShapeBase` as metaclass. As it is, `Shape` is "not a subclass of Shape" (even though `issubclass(Shape, Shape) == True`), while `Triangle` is. So, the code is maybe as it should be, but it would be less confusing if the comment wasn't there at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the second question `delattr(rv, 'size')` (and `del rv.size`) is failing because the attribute `size` is a class attribute not an instance attribute which mean is part of the class `__dict__` not the instance `__dict__`.

And the `hasattr` normally will return `True` because it search for an attribute in all the parent classes of the object passed to it.

As for why your metaclass `__new__` is called when the class body is evaluated think of it like this :

> If you create an instance of a class the class `__new__` will be called when you create the instance, yes ? so the same should apply on class , a metaclass is a class of a class so the `__new__` will be called when you create the class.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I upvoted both answers but marked yours as correct since it came first and answered both questions.

Answer (score 4):

`__new__` of a metaclass controls the instantiation of a new class, not a new instance of that class. So, when you create the class `Shape` with `ShapeBase` as the metaclass, `ShapeBase.__new__` is invoked.