# Can someone explain Python hasattr/delattr on a method attribute?

Tags: python

I've got a bug caused by some weird behavior. I might be fundamentally missing something about the semantics of function attributes. Or it may be a bug. I'm on

```
$ python
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:13:53) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
```

First I define a class, and add an attribute to one of its methods.

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...    def bar(self):
...        pass
...    bar.xyzzy = 'magic'
...
```

Now I can see that exists on `Foo.bar`

```
>>> hasattr(Foo.bar, 'xyzzy')
True
```

And I can retrieve it.

```
>>> Foo.bar.xyzzy
'magic'

>>> getattr(Foo.bar, 'xyzzy')
'magic'
```

But I can't delete it.

```
>>> del Foo.bar.xyzzy
Traceback (most recent call last):
   ...
AttributeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute 'xyzzy'

>>> delattr(Foo.bar, 'xyzzy')
Traceback (most recent call last):
   ...
AttributeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute 'xyzzy'
```

Any ideas why? I assume it is something to do with the fact that `Foo.bar` is being reported as an 'instancemethod' here, rather than an unbound method if you just ask what `Foo.bar` is. But I'm not sure if it is an expected side-effect, if I'm misunderstanding something, or if there's a bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should do :

```
del Foo.bar.im_func.xyzzy
```

The `im_func` is needed to access the real method `Foo.bar`, the `instancemethod` is a kind of decorator that deal with passing self automatically ... .

---

As i may have understand from your question while you was successfully accessing the `xyzzy` attribute of `Foo.bar` using `getattr` and like you came across the fact that `delattr` don't act the same way, and the reason of that is that internally `getattr` call the `__getattribute__` (and `__getattr__`) of the class and all the parent class of the object in the first argument until it find the attribute or raise an `AttributeError`, the same for `hasattr` which is equivalent to:

```
def hasattr(obj, attr):
    try:
        getattr(obj, attr)
    except AttributeError:
        return False
    return True
```

In the other hand `delattr` will only succeed if the attribute passed is part of the object namespace (not [his class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707558/python-new-metaclass-behavior-with-inheritance/6707641#6707641) neither his parents class) because of safety reasons (you don't want to (**try**) to delete an attribute of [object](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#object) wouldn't you :-).

Answer (score 5):

Your issue isn't with function attributes, it's with the difference between instance methods and functions. Try:

```
class A(object):
    def foo(self):
        pass
    foo.bar = 'magic'

del A.__dict__['foo'].bar
```

It will work fine. This is because here, you're actually getting the function object `foo`, not the instance method `foo`.

This distinction is gone in Python 3, and what you're trying will work fine on instance methods. See [this mailing list thread](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-January/050625.html) for the details.